# Amazon Echo Lambda function. Where are console printed?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, echo, alexa-skills-kit

Where would I need to go if I had a console.log("some stuff in here") inside my function to see it printed out for my Lambda function that AWS service provides?

Comment: You wouldn't, the lambda just executes on AWS, and that's it. If you need to test it, do it on your own computer when writing it.

Comment: @adeneo sorry I'm still a little noobish about this whole service. But wouldn't the function get called when I talk through the amazon alexa enabled device? How would I go about it to fake that?

Comment: I'm not sure how you trigger your lambda, there are a number of ways to do that, but a lambda is just a small function that runs in Node, that lets you manipulate data and do other things on different events specified by you. There is no console, there isn't even a browser or a command line, it's triggered programatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You go to AWS CloudWatch > Log Groups > Streams for /aws/lambda/.

For me the URL is

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=#logStream:group=;streamFilter=typeLogStreamPrefix

But easiest thing is probably just go to CloudWatch and look around.