# Getting error 'The target Lambda application returned a failure response target Lambda application returned a failure response'

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

The skill was working fine on day 1 while testing from an echo dot device, but now its giving a weird error as following.

> Skill response was marked as failure
>
> The target Lambda application returned a failure response

I'm not getting the cause of this error, since while testing the skill from alexa test console it was working fine, can anyone help me here for resolving this issue.

Also alexa web app is redirecting to alexa.amazon.co.uk every time I try to open alexa.amazon.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is an issue with your lambda function that you will need to figure out.

Take a look at answer here:
[Amazon Echo Lambda function. Where are console printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626463/amazon-echo-lambda-function-where-are-console-printed/39627809)

Comment: My skill is working fine when testing from alexa app test console, but giving errors when trying from echo dot, also not seeing any log recorded in the cloudwatch log.

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue from cloudwatch log, it was due to request type which was no handled in the code and was causing issue.